# Connection betwen padding and border-collapse(table)

Tags: html, css, html-table, padding

**Problem: When border-collapse is set to separate(default) padding of the table is working, but when border-collapse is collapse, padding is not working.**

Code:

HTML: https://pastebin.com/aFJPt43R (because almost the whole post is code, I need to post HTML this way)

CSS:

```
#pravila table {
    width: 50%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-color: white;
    margin: 0px 25% 0px 25%;
    padding: 50px;
}

#pravila th, td {
    border: 3px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Screenshots:[image]
[image]

Comment: Include the code here.

Comment: When value is "collapse" -> border-spacing and empty-cells properties have no effect https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp. You can add the padding to the parent element of the table and achieve your styling.

Comment: Maybe I didn’t express myself well when border-collapse: collapse; of table padding doesn't work.

Comment: Code is included in the post, HTML, and CSS part.